# Equivalent of getCurrentUser().getUid() of a Google log in on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, uid

I'm using something like this to get the UID from a Google logged in user on Firebase.

```
 private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        String idGoogle = account.getId();
}
....
```

But this is giving me some headaches because then I have to pass that String through intents. Isn't there a getCurrentUser().getUid() like when one use the email and password log in? Everytime I check on the documentation there's only instructions for email and password log in, but not how to handle google accounts when already logged in.

Comment: Why not to use the uid that is coming from the FirebaseUser object?

Comment: If I do something like this:
                                mDatabase.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("score").setValue(Integer.parseInt(b.getTag().toString()));

I get this error:

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
'
Aren't Firebaseuser and google user completely different things?

Comment: That's a different issue than the one you are asking here. I suggest you add a new question regarding that issue.